# Can you create a wifi hotspot but block internet access to it?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I want to quickly create a local network to share files, stream content or use LAN applications with some devices. However, I do not want these devices to be able to connect to the internet because I don't want them running off and updating themselves for example.

The way I've done this is to just unplug the ethernet from my desktop when I want to do it, but there must be a way to keep internet in my desktop and just not share it, and none of the networks in my control panel seem to have "share internet through this network" enabled

EDIT: Didn't mention specific devices since I didn't think it was important, but since someone asked, the main thing I would like to have in a LAN with my desktop but not give access to the internet is my Oculus Quest, I don't want it installing updates or sending data back as much as I can help it, but I want it on the same LAN as my desktop for wireless pcvr

Comment: What devices? Please [edit] the question and be specific.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't see how the device is relevant to blocking access to the internet to the hosted network itself, but I edited with the info.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
Control panel -> Network and sharing center -> Change adapter settings

And then:

Right click on the adapter -> Properties -> Sharing (Tab) -> Uncheck "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection"

Comment: But that is the thing, I create a wifi hotspot, connect a device, go to adapter settings, right click each and every adapter, go to the Sharing tab and none have the "allow other network users connect thorugh this computer's internet connection" checked